# Rails Admin 0.5.0 Custom CSS / wysihtml5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I add a css file to the admin panel?

I've tried this: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Theming-and-customization

In app: app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/custom/theming.css.scss

I view page source and it does not show.

I just want to add https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails CSS and Javascript to the admin panel.

For some reason in production the bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails editor does not display.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that rails admin is using path: /assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css and /assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js and what is compiled might be something like /assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5-xyz22323.css, etc.

I just added the plain files: /assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css and /bootstrap-wysihtml5.js to the public directory.

Comment: I get these two file at [this link](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/tree/master/src), and put them to public but it does not work. Do i need to add in `config.assets.precompile` in production.rb ? or I need to run `rake assets:precompile` ? Hope you can help. Thanks you. P/s: I am using Rails 4 and rails_admin 0.5.0

Comment: can you show me your production.rb file and application.css, application.js files ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, please ensure you're using the correct paths and name for the css and js files. The should be public/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css and public/assets/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js . If I remember correct, rake assets:precompile should have no effect. These files are as is in the public folder. I am using rails admin 0.5.0. Remember this as well: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Wysihtml5

Comment: Hi, my solution to fix this problem is copy css and js files to public/assets folder on server, so the server can find them to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5({
  ...
  stylesheets: ["<%= asset_path('your-css-file.css') %>"]
});
```